# Error in JOIN while using Common Table Expresion

Tags: mysql, join, relational-database, common-table-expression

I am using the expression below to find out which 'resource' type customers have 'work_resource' that are active.

```
WITH cte_ss AS (SELECT wr.user_id
FROM work w
JOIN work_resource wr ON wr.work_id = w.id
WHERE wr.work_resource_status_type_code = 'active'
  ),
SELECT u.uuid
FROM user u
JOIN company c ON c.id = u.company_id
LEFT JOIN cte_ss on cte_ss.user_id = u.id
    AND c.customer_type = 'resource'
```

White trying to run this, I get the following error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT u.uuid
FROM user u
JOIN company c ON c.id = u.company_id
LEFT JOIN cte_ss' at line 6
```

Both the individual queries (without the LEFT JOIN) are working, so not sure what I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cte would look like this

But as i don't know nothing about your tables, you have to figure it out yourself

```
WITH cte_ss AS (
SELECT 
user_id
FROM work w
JOIN work_resource wr ON wr.work_id = w.id
WHERE wr.work_resource_status_type_code = 'active'
)
SELECT u.uuid
FROM user u
JOIN company c ON c.id = u.company_id
LEFT JOIN cte_ss on cte_ss.user_id = u.id
    AND c.customer_type = 'resource'
```

Comment: oops sorry didnt realize there was a formatting error

Comment: so that worked, but 'work' does not have 'user_id' field, work_resource does. Why does it not work if I put wr.user_id inside the CTE expression?

Comment: As i told in my answer i don't know your table structure, i don't know what result you are searching .... for a [mre] you would need to provide much more information